# Equivalent of HTMLLoader class for an AS3 only project?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, air

I'm building an as3 only web application and want to be able to include external html content within a flash 'window'. In AIR there is the flash.html.HTMLLoader class which makes this possible.

Can anyone point to an example of this being done in a flash as opposed to AIR application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading the HTML content, i really recommend you [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/).

To display the html, just use [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/TextField.html#text/TextField#htmlText) with htmlText. But please, be aware that just some tags are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know its an old post but here goes anyways. Requires AIR as publish setting.

```
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
//web broswer with window
private var html_browser:HTMLLoader; 
//if not constructed
if (html_browser == null || html_browser.stage.nativeWindow.closed) {
    //options
    var pulse_initOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions(); 
    //bounds
    var pulse_bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20, 984, 590); 
    //create window
    html_browser = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, pulse_initOptions, true, pulse_bounds);                
}
//url
var pulse_urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com");
//load
html_browser.load(pulse_urlReq); 
//bring to front
html_browser.stage.nativeWindow.activate();
//visible
html_browser.stage.nativeWindow.visible = true;
```

Comment: OP specifically specified AS3-only.

Answer (score 0):

I know the Dynamic Text object in the visual editor has a property to support HTML formatting. You will just use URLRequest and URLLoader classes to get your data, then stuff it in the textbox. I don't know if this is robust enough for you, but I can't find any other way to do this. Please let us know if you do.